# Read the XML attributes in a custom class Android

Tags: java, android, xml, resources

I'm implementing a custom Preference class with a progress bar and a icon following [that guide](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html).

I'd like to put the resource of the image for the icon in the XML-file and retrieve it from there when drawing the Preference. Something like:

```
<amir.android.icebreaking.SeekBarPreference  
    android:dependency="Main_Option"
    android:key="customPref"
    android:defaultValue="32"
    android:src="@drawable/myicon"
    android:title="Custom Preference"
/>
```

How can I get the `@drawable/myicon` resource or resource id programmatically later?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.myicon);

that should work